# Parts for "Simple Machine" book by Isogawa-san?

Tags: technic, part-identification, piece-information, books

I would like to make some models from [The LEGO Technic Idea Book: Simple Machine by Yoshihito Isogawa](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272774).

It seems the author is using parts of different "Technic" sets.

Could you advise where can I get parts (or ideally a set) to make the models for the book?

Comment: so cool, I did not know that Isogawa wrote books, his youtube films are so much fun and his usage of lego bricks is highly innovative. I will order one book now, thanx for the info.

Comment: It is a truly excellent series of books.  These are the most elegant of all of the LEGO books I've ever seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a lot there, but the very last sentence from your *Amazon* link mentions to visit the *[No Starch Press](http://www.isogawastudio.co.jp/legostudio/others/ideabook_partslist.html)* website for a list of the special parts used in the book.

There the website includes all three books from the author's 
 LEGO Technic series:

- *The LEGO Technic Idea Book: Simple Machines.* (Digital PDF of book *[here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiV2bqDv6vgAhVJs6wKHcDdA0QQFjAAegQICRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.pakkau.edu.hk%2F~lamchitai%2Febook%2FThe%2520LEGO%2520Technic%2520Idea%2520Book.pdf&usg=AOvVaw078XtYuXFAHjzbrmYUhimM)*.)
- *The LEGO Technic Idea Book: Wheeled Wonders.*
- *The LEGO Technic Idea Book: Fantastic Contraptions.*

All with a few set recommendations directly from the author, where he suggests sets that have a wide range of parts in single set purchases.

For parts left over, he offers a reference list with colored pictures of each part, and purchasing links to *Bricklink.com*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Isogawa uses a large range of colored bricks to show the mechanisms. There is no single real set you can buy that contains all the parts. If you really need to have the exact same colored bricks you would need to look into buying them separately. However this might get a little tedious or expensive. Any other bricks in common colors would work nicely as well.

There are many ways of buying the needed bricks separately. You may wish to check [Bricklink](http://bricklink.com), [Brickowl](http://brickowl.com) or [LEGO Pick-a-Brick](https://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Pick-a-Brick) selection.

Answer (score 1):

www.bricklink.com is a great place to find parts!